# No se me encriptan las contraseñas en MySQL

Tags: php, seguridad

Lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario, pero despues de que lo pude conectar a MySQL, ahora quiero `encriptar` las contraseñas. Investigue sobre `password_hash()`, pero no se como colocarlo en mi codigo.

Aqui les dejo mi codigo `PHP`

```
<?php 

$PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_comentarios;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try { 
  echo "datos enviados correctamente";

$sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO prueba1(nombre, email, clave, comentario) VALUES (:nombre, :email, :clave, :comentario)");
$sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
$sql->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
$sql->bindParam(':clave', password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT));
$sql->bindParam(':comentario',$_POST['comentario']);
$sql->Execute();



 }catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Fallo de conexion al enviar los datos:".$e ->getMessage();
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Deberías usar el algoritmo `password_hash()` del modo siguiente para hacer el **hash**  de tus contraseñas

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

> Como bien me hizo la observación @Xerif, asignamos el valor devuelto por `password_hash()` y luego esa variable la pasamos al método `$sql->bindParam()` y con eso ya no tenemos que usar la línea `error_reporting(0)`

En la siguiente línea de código te debería funcionar así

**Hashear el valor de POST y asignar a una variable**

```
$contrasenia = password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

**A bindParam le pasas la variable que recién acabamos de declarar**

```
$sql->bindParam(':clave', $contrasenia);
```

Te debería generar un resultado similar al siguiente

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGygf3kk1a
```

Lo estoy colocando como método que envuelve a la variable `$_POST` ya que es esta la que contiene el valor dinámico que deseamos cifrar.

> La opción que coloque como segundo parámetro que dice `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` Usa el algoritmo bcrypt (predeterminado a partir de PHP 5.5.0), esta constante está diseñada para cambiar siempre que se añada un algoritmo nuevo y más fuerte a PHP. Por esta razón, la longitud del resultado de usar este identificador puede cambiar con el tiempo. Por lo tanto, se recomienda almacenar el resultado en una columna de una base de datos que pueda ampliarse a más de 60 caracteres (**255 caracteres sería una buena elección**).

Comment: Acabo de lanzarme esto: Advertencia: password_hash () espera al menos 2 parámetros, 1 dado en C:, y esto: Estándares estrictos: solo las variables deben pasarse por referencia en C.

Comment: Ahora me quedo esto: Estándares estrictos: solo las variables deben pasarse por referencia en C

Comment: Dame un momento que modifique el codigo, creo que lo estoy colocando mal. Edite el codigo para que lo veas.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar  @MateoGomez?

Comment: si, te deje una captura de pantalla, miraste el codigo?? lo edite tambien para que revises

Comment: @MateoGomez agrega justo despues de la etiqueta `<?php` este código `error_reporting(0);` prueba nuevamente tu código, revisa la base de datos y dime si se almacena el registro

Comment: ya funciona, te lo agradezco mucho, Shadow

Comment: @shadow Hacer esto `error_reporting(0);` para esconder los errores en lugar de solucionarlos es una malicia idea. Lo correcto en este caso sería asignar `password_hash($_POST['clave'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT)` a una variable para pasarela al `bindParam()` en lugar de pasarle el resultado directamente. Ya que un string no se puede referencia y `bindParam()` espera una referencia según la documentación.

Comment: @shadow con permiso edite tu respuesta, me mal interpretaste, el error venia de no pasarle una variable a `bindParam()` no a `password_hash()`, un saludo.